# solace hermesjms kerberos authentication

Tags: kerberos, solace, hermes-jms

I am following this guide https://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/hermes-jms/

to use hermesJMS(downloaded via SOAPUI) with solace.

In our organization we only use kerberos authentication for solace so my question is how do I setup  kerberos auth with hermesjms ?

Our sample subscriber code which works would look some thing like:

```
    final JCSMPProperties properties = new JCSMPProperties();
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.HOST, "hostname:5432");
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.VPN_NAME, "vpn_name"); 
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.USERNAME, "username");

    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:\\Solace\\kerberos.conf"); 
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\Solace\\app.conf"); // this references a keytab file and sets principal and realm etc


    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME, JCSMPProperties.AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_GSS_KRB);
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.KRB_SERVICE_NAME, "XXX");

    final JCSMPSession session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties);
    .....
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put the java properties for Kerberos in the Hermes property list, when setting the connection parameters. See a guide below: https://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/hermes-jms/
​